# Windows autoupdate cscope database from GVIM

Tags: vim, cscope

I work with GVIM and cscope for C on Window 7. But, the cscope database gets soon outdated as and when code is updated. So, I added the following to my gvimrc

```
nmap <F11>  :cs k 0 <CR> :!cscope -bR <CR> :cs a cscope.out<CR>
```

Since, I almost always work with only one cscope database, it is sufficient to kill only the first cscope database connection. However, when I execute cscope command it does not run from my project root directory. I can't figure out how to instruct cscope/cmd.exe to run cscope from project directory from within GVIM.

How to achieve this. Are there any well known plugins available for this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this plugin I made: https://github.com/mihaifm/bck

Among other things it has a `ChangeToRoot` command, which changes Vim's current working directory to the project root of the current file.

The project root is defined by the presence of several files/folders (root markers). The defaults are: `['.git/', '.git', '_darcs/', '.hg/', '.bzr/', '.svn/', 'Gemfile']`

You can customize it with the `g:BckRoots` variable in your `.vimrc`. You probably need to add `.sln` in there if you're compiling with Visual Studio.

Anyway, after this, your mapping should look like this:

```
nmap <F11>  :cs k 0 <CR> :!cscope -bR <CR>:ChangeToRoot<CR>:cs a cscope.out<CR>
```

It will load that `cscope.out` from your project root.